# iOS application is rejected when because of jailbreaking check (in Crashlytics)

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

Recently after minor application update iTunesConnect rejected build with following letter:

> From Apple
>   1. 1 Safety: Objectionable Content Hello,
>
> Thank you for your continued patience.
>
> To resolve the previously communicated issue, it would be appropriate
>   for your next submission to have its jailbreaking check classes and
>   methods removed.
>
> We look forward to reviewing your resubmission.
>
> Best regards,
>
> App Store Review

I've tried to find framework which has such classes/methods and the only one framework was found - it's Crashlytics:

```
WowSuchProject bernikowich$ grep -lr "Cydia" * | grep -v .svn | grep -v .md
Pods/Crashlytics/iOS/Crashlytics.framework/Crashlytics
```

But I have many apps including Crashlytics framework without any issues. Solution?

Comment: Appeal the rejection, explaining that you use Crashlytics.

Comment: I've never heard of an app using Crashlytics get rejected because of this. I agree with @Gereon's suggestion.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. I have also not heard of this being an issue before, if an appeal doesn't work, please let me know.

Comment: @MikeBonnell I’ve resubmit new build with no issues. Maybe it was just unlucky day.)

Comment: Glad it's all set Timur :)